# Which interface declares truncatedTo() Java 8 date API?

Tags: java-8, date

I want to write generic implementation that truncate current date to next midnight (00:00:00). It should operate on `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`:

```
td.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
```

The problem is that I can't find interface that declare `truncatedTo` method...

It there alternative way to implement this function generically?

Comment: If the method was declared in an interface, [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) would show it. Compare to [`plus` beneath it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plus-java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount-) and its “Specified by:” sections.

Comment: The doc for java.time generally advises against using the superclasses/interfaces, and orders us to use only the concrete classes in our apps’ business logic. The superclasses/interfaces are largely intended for internal use only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would see in its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) if the `truncatedTo​(TemporalUnit unit)` method was declared in some interface.

You can fall back to Temporal's [`with(TemporalAdjuster adjuster)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-) to handle it generically:

```
private static <T extends Temporal> T roll(T t) {
    return (T) t.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).with(LocalTime.MIN);
}
```

You have to be careful and check your requirements whether this does the right thing for you.

Alternatively there is plain old **method overloading** to handle both `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` with at least the same method name:

```
private static LocalDateTime roll(LocalDateTime t) {
    return t.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}

private static ZonedDateTime roll(ZonedDateTime t) {
    return t.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot readily implement this function generically. There is no interface specifying the `truncatedTo` method. Also `LocalDateTime.truncatedTo()` returns a `LocalDateTime` while the like-named method in `ZonedDateTime` returns a (you already know) `ZonedDateTime`.

Six classes in total have a `truncatedTo` method. `Instant`, `LocalTime`, `OffsetDateDateTime` and `OffsetTime` have too. In all cases does the method return the same type again.

The commonality probably could have been made more explicit using generics. I heard it said that Stephen Colebourne, the chief developer of `java.time`, wasn’t fond of generics, and in any case there aren’t any in the API.

Many other methods are present with the same name in several date-time classes without being specified in a common interface, like `format`, `getDayOfMonth`, `isAfter` and the `withXx` methods.

It would probably be possible to implement a generic function using reflection, but you don’t want that.

Comment: So this is by design... OK